# __importDefault is not defined Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, command-line-interface, capacitor

I'm trying to run my project but I'm facing this type of error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined
at Module../src/app/app.component.ts (app.component.ts:9)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Module../src/main.ts (environment.ts:16)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
```

Where am I wrong?

ionic-info (command):

```
    Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.2.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
   @angular/cli                  : 9.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.2.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.5.1
   @capacitor/core : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res (update available: 0.9.0) : 0.6.0
   native-run (update available: 0.3.0)  : 0.2.8

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   NodeJS     : v10.16.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.14.2
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.3.1 Build version 11C504
```

Comment: whats the TS version you are using

Comment: "typescript": "^3.7.5"

Comment: try downgrading your TS. Downgrade to typeScript to 3.5.3 which fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the issue with the TS version. Try downgrading your TS version to 3.5.3:

```
npm install typescript@~3.5.3
```

package.json should be like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.5.3 was found instead.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

Comment: Try with version 3.6.4

Comment: Now with ionic serve it works, also with iOs, but with Android I got: JavaScript Error: {"type":"js.error","error":{"message":"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )","url":"http://localhost/vendor-es5.js","line":931,"col":47,"errorObject":"{}"}} and the screen is white

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue while updating angular, I solved this by updating @angular-devkit to the same version as @angular/core.